# Regex in middle of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

how I can check some string with regex in some part

I want to join these condition.

```
if ($string == "form[new_search_param][1][searchParam]") {}
```

and

```
 if ($string == "form[new_search_param][2][searchParam]") {}
```

to some sort of this

```
if ($string == "form[new_search_param][" . ^[0-9] . "[searchParam]") {}
```

I wonder if I can use regex in string?

Comment: yes. you can. you're very close to the solution, too. now just start with using a regex-function instead of string comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
if( preg_match( '/form\[new_search_param\]\[[0-9]\]\[searchParam\]/', $string )) {}
```

Square brackets have to be escaped in a regular expression.

Note: This will not match the string:

```
form[new_search_param][10][searchParam]
```

since you are looking for exact one number. To accept one or more numbers write:

```
if( preg_match( '/form\[new_search_param\]\[[0-9]+\]\[searchParam\]/', $string )) {}
```

Additional suggestion:

```
if( preg_match( '/^form\[new_search_param\]\[\d+\]\[searchParam\]$/', $string )) {}
```

This will not match if there is additional content before or behind the search phrase like:

```
prefixedtext_form[new_search_param][10][searchParam]_suffixedtext
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `preg_match`:

> Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
if(preg_match("/form\[new_search_param\]\[[0-9]\]\[searchParam\]/", $string)) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: The above solution will work. However, you can also use `\d` as a shorthand for `[0-9]`. If you want numbers higher than 9, use `\d+` to select one or more numerical digits.